# How to hide user profile(edit current password, email, picture, everything) based on role?

Tags: 7, users

When user logged in with common shared username and password, I wanted to hide user profile for some of the user based on the given role.

So, I want a feature where user can just logged in and logged out with the given shared user name and password and, I don't want to allow them to change their password or I don't want to allow them to edit in their profile.

I have created separate role for this users.

I came to know that we can hide edit user profile with CSS:

```
display: none;
```

Is there any other way to hide user profile based on some roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I found [**User Protect module**](https://www.drupal.org/project/userprotect) very helpful. 
It gives the exact same functionality that what I wanted.

We can hide edit account, edit password, email from based on user roles and for specific users too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set access for fields as FALSE as per user roles.

```
function YOURMODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if(in_array('your_role_name',$user->roles)) {
    $form['account']['pass']['#access'] = FALSE;
    // Similarly other fields, but fields can not be required fields on profile.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a quick method would be to theme the user profile template file and do a quick check for the role there.  seeing as you're okay with that css approach, I'm guessing this is more of a nice to have rather than some mission critical thing,  so I think this would work nicely for you.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7

Answer (score 0):

[User role field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_role_field) module allows you to specify role-specific fields. When creating a new field, you specify what roles this field is enabled for.

Fields are only visible and editable if a user has a specific role.

This role does not determine access controls for visible fields. You could use the [Field Permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) for setting access controls.

More then 120 sites currently use this module.